# Mono for Android, TabHost with abs to swap Views within the same Activity

Tags: android, mono, android-tabhost

I'm new to Mono for Android, and I'm trying to port an old application, and I'm having difficulties with TabHost ...

In the tutorials page Xamarin writes:
"You can implement your tab content in one of two ways: use the tabs to swap Views within the same Activity, or use the tabs to change between entirely separate activities. 
In this tutorial, you'll create a tabbed UI that uses a separate Activity for each tab."

Someone can help developing something "use the tabs to swap Views within the same Activity"?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Now you have tabs on the ActionBar, and your "content" zone will be made of fragments.

Follow this link for further explanation and tutorial on how to add tabs to your app:
http://docs.xamarin.com/Android/Guides/Platform_Features/Introduction_to_Ice_Cream_Sandwich#Action_Bar_Tabs